# SignalR: Single vs different dto types for the single vs different client methods

Tags: c#, signalr

Which is considered the best practice for using single vs different dto types for the single vs different client methods?
As an example, 3 options for 'notify progress and errors' problem:

1. Single method, different dto types.

```
class ProgressResponse { int Progress; T1 IntermediateResult .. }
class FinalResponse { int Progress; T2 FinalResult .. }
class ErrorResponse { int StatusCode; string Message .. }
...
Clients.Caller.onProgress(new ProgressResponse(..));
Clients.Caller.onProgress(new FinalResponse(..));
Clients.Caller.onProgress(new ErrorResponse(..));
```

2. Different methods, different dto types.

```
class ProgressResponse { int Progress; T1 IntermediateResult .. }
class FinalResponse { int Progress; T2 FinalResult .. }
class ErrorResponse { int StatusCode; string Message .. }
...
Clients.Caller.onProgress(new ProgressResponse(..));
Clients.Caller.onCompleted(new FinalResponse(..));
Clients.Caller.onError(new ErrorResponse(..));
```

3. Different methods, single dto type.

```
class HugeResponse { int Progress; int IsFinal; T IntermediateResult;
                  .. int StatusCode; string Message .. }
...
Clients.Caller.onProgress(new HugeResponse(..));
Clients.Caller.onCompleted(new HugeResponse(..));
Clients.Caller.onError(new HugeResponse(..));
```

What if there are different Progress response types which require different properties?
And these progress response types may or may not be inherited from ProgressResponse class.

```
class ProgressResponse1 { int Progress; T3 Prop3; T4 Prop4.. }
class ProgressResponse2 { int Progress; T5 Prop5; T6 Prop6 .. }
```

The client-side would have to subscribe to all these methods and deal with state:

```
private subscribe() {
  let onErrorReceived$  = this.connection.listenFor('onError');
  onErrorReceived$.subscribe((response: ErrorResponse) => {
    ...
  });
  let onCompletedReceived$  = this.connection.listenFor('onCompleted');
  onCompletedReceived$.subscribe((response: FinalResponse ) => {
    ...
  });
  let onProgressReceived$  = this.connection.listenFor('onProgress');
  onProgressReceived$.subscribe((response: ProgressResponse) => {
    ...
  });
  let onProgress1Received$  = this.connection.listenFor('onProgress1');
  onProgress1Received$.subscribe((response: Progress1Response) => {
    ...
  });
  let onProgress2Received$  = this.connection.listenFor('onProgress2');
  onProgress2Received$.subscribe((response: Progress2Response) => {
    ...
  });
  ...
}
```

Comment: I personally would use different types, inheriting from a single common type or implementing a single interface. reason for that is that you don't need to send giant objects with properties you don't use.

Comment: What about different methods? Like onProgress, onError, onSuccess vs single onResponse?

Comment: Generally, dto's (data transfer objects) do not have methods. it's only meant to transfer data. I personally would split those methods off anyway

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. The methods here is SignalR client methods, i.e. server-side hub calls say web client's onProgress using websockets.

I.e. on client-side one'd have to deal with same chosen server-side option.

Comment: I have no experience with that, but i don't see how that's relevant anyway...